# How to purge CloudFront's cache

Tags: amazon-s3

I would like to know if it's possible to clear CloudFront's cache,

The file concerned has changed on Amazon S3 but it's not being updated on CloudFront.

Comment: Related: [How do you invalidate cache for a static site?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35427518/55075)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer using Python:

```
import boto
cf = boto.connect_cloudfront('aws_access_key_id', 'aws_secret_access_key')
cf.create_invalidation_request("distribution_id", ["/path1","/path2"])
```

Documentation:

- [`boto.connect_cloudfront`](http://boto.s3.amazonaws.com/ref/boto.html#boto.connect_cloudfront)
- [`create_invalidation_request`](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/cloudfront.html#boto.cloudfront.CloudFrontConnection.create_invalidation_request)

Comment: I was wondering how to get the distribution_id. Found it through the python shell, with help of http://boto.s3.amazonaws.com/ref/cloudfront.html

Comment: Is a distribution id safe to hard-code in public source code or is it "sensitive" information (like the aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key) that should be provided say, as an environment variable?

Answer (score 7):

Might be useful to know you can also do this right from the AWS Console.

- *Distribution Settings > Invalidations > Create Invalidation*

Then just type in the paths to invalidate in the same format displayed there.

See: [Invalidating Objects (Web Distributions Only)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html).

Comment: By far the easiest point-and-click method. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In case you use *Google Chrome*, you can use [Cloudfront Purge Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gadbenpggeagjgnameagcpjnjdlckkpb) plugin.

<sup>**Disclaimer**: I'm the author.</sup>

Features include:

- Do purge requests for all distributions tied to your credentials
- View the status of the last 20 purge requests
- Receive a Desktop Notification when the purge is done (can be turned off)

The source code is available on Github: https://github.com/sajal/Cloudfront-Purge-Tool

Comment: Do you have an example of what a purge request looks like using the plugin? I'm confused on how that works.

Comment: What the complete url u wanna purge? if it is http://example.com/foo/bar.jpg you need to enter /foo/bar.jpg in the box

Comment: Works perfectly.  It took about 10 minutes to purge cache for one image, but that's Amazon's fault.  Thanks a lot for this!